# How to change <p:calendar> language

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, localization, calendar

the `<p:calendar>` default language is English, I want to change it to French
I added `local="fr"` but nothing has changed
I add `lang="fr"` nothing has changed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add script to you page in which localization for calendar is defined. You can see it on [Primefaces calendar i18n](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/PrimeFacesLocales)

Comment: simply import it in my xhtml page ?

Comment: And to use the language you've just defined in the i18n `.js` you need to specify the `locale`.  For instance `<p:calendar ... locale="fr" ... />`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes even though if you change local in code and if it doesn't work then you need to change Browser settings and change local as French or English.
IE --> Tools --> Internet Options --> Under General tab --> languages and add language.